# streaming operator overloading for nested type names inside templates

Tags: c++, c++17

The following code does not compile:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <optional>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

namespace dbj {

    template< typename K, typename V >
    class top final {
        static_assert(
          ! is_same_v<K,V>, 
          " to make things simpler K and V must be different types"
        );
    public:
        // nested type names
        using key_type = optional<K>;
        using val_type = optional<V>;
        using type = top;

    private:
        key_type key_{};
        val_type val_{};
    public:
        top() = delete;
        explicit top(K k, V v) : key_(k), val_(v) {}

    private:    
        // PROBLEM A: not found by 
        // friend wostream & operator << (wostream & os, type top_) 
        friend wostream & operator << (wostream & os, key_type key_arg_ ) {
            return os << L"\nK  : " << key_arg_.value_or(K{});
        }

        // PROBLEM B: not found by
        // friend wostream & operator << (wostream & os, type top_) 
        friend wostream & operator << ( wostream & os, val_type val_arg_ ) {
            return os << L"\nV  : " << val_arg_.value_or(V{});
        }

        // found no problem
        friend wostream & operator << (wostream & os, type top_) 
        {
            // ISSUE D: this is not looking for overloads in the immediate scope
            // i.e. inside the template class
            // this is first looking for operator declaration inside namespace dbj
            return os << L"\n\nprinting dbj::top<K,V> : " << top_.key_ << L"," << top_.val_;
        }

    }; // top
} // dbj ns

using top_type = dbj::top<wstring, int>;

extern "C"  int test_operator_overloading_puzzle()
{
    top_type top_{ L"the key", 42 };
    std::wcout << top_ << std::endl;
    return 1;
}
```

Also available here: https://wandbox.org/permlink/jMKpn6CKFL2cyceO

Every compiler complains that within the streaming operator for `type top_`, no match is found for streaming `top_.key` (marked ISSUE D in the code above). Why can't lookup find the two streaming functions I declared directly above them?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what the actual question is. Since it compiles - what is the actual behavior and what is the desired behavior?

Comment: Coincidentally this example uses `optional` but this question is otherwise unrelated to `optional` and unrelated to any specific C++ version. I would remove tag `c++17` and add tag `linker`.

Comment: I deleted my answer because the question is quite different now compared to what it was initially.

Comment: @PatrickFromberg , no it is not different it is the same issue. Barry just removed all the cruft. the tag C++17 stays and the tag 'linker' you requested still does not make any sense here.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simpler reproduction:

```
namespace A {
  struct X { };
}

namespace B {
  struct Y {
    A::X x;

    // #1
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, A::X) {
      return os;
    }

    // #2
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Y y) {
      return os << y.x; // error: no match for operator<<
    }
  };
}
```

This is because of how name lookup works. When you declare and define a namespace-scope friend function like this, that function can *only* be found by argument-dependent lookup of its arguments. It is never found by regular unqualified lookup.

But the function you're declaring in `#1` isn't actually in the associated namespace of any of its arguments - the function is declared in `namespace B`, but its two arguments are in `namespace std` and `namespace A`, respectively. As a result, when we write `os << y.x`, no matching candidates are found by regular unqualified lookup and then no candidates are found by argument-dependent lookup either - `#1` is not in the right namespace. Hence, no candidates.

The shortest solution is to just add a namespace-scope declaration of `#1` outside of `struct Y`:

```
namespace B {
  std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, A::X);

  struct Y { ... };
}
```

Now, this function can be found by regular unqualified lookup, so the call in `#2` works. But really, there's no reason to have declared `#1` as a friend function with `B::Y` (it in no way refers to `B::Y`), so just declare it externally. It also doesn't work very well as a streaming operator, so probably just make it a regular function instead.

Comment: So it is legal that a free function declaration can serve as declaration of a friend function? I now vaguely believe to remember that I saw code in the STL that depends on that feature. Can you remind me where please?

Comment: @PatrickFromberg I don't understand the question. You can friend already-existing functions, and you can provide a declaration for a friend function you declared within a class definition.

Comment: @Barry thanks this is simple and works too. I already made it a regular function in my problem inducing code.

Comment: @Barry, the thing I did not know was that you can declare the friend function outside of the class without the class name qualification and friend specification. But I see now that this makes sense.

Comment: If one makes `friend operator <<` , inside A::X that would also work. the issue I was having is I could not do that since my nested type name was std::optional<T>, in that case the way out is indeed to declare the requested operator where name lookup can find it.

Answer (score 0):

Just building on top of Barry's simplification of the question and then on top of his answer.

```
namespace {

    using namespace std;

    namespace A {
        struct X { 
            // #1 --> SOLUTION to problem #1 
            // friend operator is here in the scope where
            // name lookup can find it, declared and defined
            friend wostream& operator<<(wostream& os, X) {
                return os << L"A::X" ;
            }
        };
    }

    namespace B {
        struct Y {
            A::X x;

            // #1 --> PROBLEM: name lookup can not find this 
            // as it is in the scope unrelated to A::X
            /*
            friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, A::X) {
                return os;
            }
            */

            // #2
            friend wostream& operator<<(wostream& os, Y y) {
                // << y.x is normally found inside the 
                // type of x and that is A::X
                return os << L"\nB::Y --> " << y.x; 
            }
        };
    }

    void test_barry() {
        B::Y by_;

        wcout << by_;
    }
}
```

This is for the situations when we can insert the necessary friend operator inside the nested type. Otherwise please see Barry's answer.

For further education opportunity perhaps [this is a good start](https://web.mst.edu/~nmjxv3/articles/templates.html).